# Rails redirect_to post method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
    redirect_to :controller=>'groups',:action=>'invite'
```

but I got error because redirect_to send GET method I want to change this method to 'POST' there is no :method option in redirect_to what will I do ? Can I do this without redirect_to.

Edit:

I have this in groups/invite.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Send invite", group_members_path(:group_member=>{:user_id=>friendship.friend.id,  :group_id=>@group.id,:sender_id=>current_user.id,:status=>"requested"}), :method => :post %>
```

This link call create action in group_members controller,and after create action performed I want to show groups/invite.html.erb with group_id(I mean after click 'send invite' group_members will be created and then the current page will be shown) like this:

```
redirect_to :controller=>'groups',:action=>'invite',:group_id=>@group_member.group_id
```

After redirect_to request this with GET method, it calls show action in group and take invite as id and give this error

```
Couldn't find Group with ID=invite
```

My invite action in group

```
    def invite
@friendships = current_user.friendships.find(:all,:conditions=>"status='accepted'")
@requested_friendships=current_user.requested_friendships.find(:all,:conditions=>"status='accepted'")
@group=Group.find(params[:group_id])
 end
```

The solution is I have to redirect this with POST method but I couldn't find a way.

Ugly solution: I solved this problem which I don't prefer. I still wait if you have solution in fair way.

My solution is add route for invite  to get rid of  'Couldn't find Group with ID=invite' error.

in routes.rb

```
   map.connect "/invite",:controller=>'groups',:action=>'invite'
```

in create action

```
   redirect_to "/invite?group_id=#{@group_member.group_id}"
```

I call this solution in may language 'amele yontemi' in english 'manual worker method' (I think).

Comment: why would you want to it this way? could you provide more context?

Comment: Agree, we need more information about what you are attempting to achieve before we can really give you a good answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect\_to using POST in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting tripped up by how Rails routing works. This code:

```
redirect_to :controller=>'groups',:action=>'invite',:group_id=>@group_member.group_id
```

creates a URL that looks something like `/groups/invite?group_id=1`.

Without the mapping in your `routes.rb`, the Rails router maps this to the `show` action, not `invite`. The `invite` part of the URL is mapped to `params[:id]` and when it tries to find that record in the database, it fails and you get the message you found.

If you are using RESTful routes, you already have a `map.resources` line that looks like this:

```
map.resources :groups
```

You need to add a custom action for `invite`:

```
map.resources :groups, :member => { :invite => :get }
```

Then change your reference to `params[:group_id]` in the `#invite` method to use just `params[:id]`.

Answer (score 45):

The answer is that you cannot do a POST using a `redirect_to`.

This is because what `redirect_to` does is just send an HTTP 30x redirect header to the browser which in turn GETs the destination URL, and browsers do only GETs on redirects

Comment: Yeah I got this but is there any way to solve my problem with redirect_to or without ?

Answer (score 5):

I found a semi-workaround that I needed to make this happen in Rails 3.  I made a route that would call the method in that controller that requires a post call.  A line in "route.rb", such as:

```
match '/create', :to => "content#create"
```

It's probably ugly but desperate times call for desperate measures.  Just thought I'd share.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to make a 'redirect' while under the hood you generate a form with method :post.

I was facing the same problem and extracted the solution into the gem `repost`, so it is doing all that work for you, so no need to create a separate view with the form, just use the provided by gem function `redirect_post()` on your controller.

```rb
class MyController < ActionController::Base
...
  def some_action
    redirect_post('url', params: {}, options: {})
  end
...
end
```

Should be available on rubygems.