# Redirect_to with post params

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I write this redirection :

```
redirect_to list_order_submit_path(:provider_id => @cart_item.product.provider.id)
```

But this show the Provider_id in URL:

> localhost:3000/order/list?provider_id=1

How can i pass the variable not in URL or how I make this get to a post param ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll quote the beginning of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144391/ruby-on-rails-post-parameters-on-redirect-to) for later viewers:

> You can't do a redirect and send POST data at the same time in the
>   HTTP spec.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it. What you want is a GET petition because you are listing elements and not modifying them.

So passing the argument in the header is correct and the best practice.