# rails 3, am I not using redirect_to correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, http-post

This should be the easiest thing in the world, but a POST redirect is not working.

A remote system normally POSTs data to one of my methods "mainhandler'

In one situation, though, it POSTs data to a different handler "noaudio" which is SUPPOSED to simply erase a session variable then "pass the POST" on to the normal handler ("mainhandler")

My route:

```
  match '/mainhandler' =>"widgets#mainhandler"
```

My code:

```
def noaudio
  puts "**** NOAUDIO"
  session[:audiofile] = ""
  redirect_to "/mainhandler"
end

def mainhandler
  puts "**** NEVER GETS HERE FROM NOAUDIO ??"
end
```

what I see in the log (below) it LOOKS like the redirect happens but the handler "mainhandler" is never executed... I see the "puts" in the noaudio handler and I see what looks like a good redirect... but mainhandler never gets executed.

```
**** NOAUDIO

Started POST "/noaudio" for 1.2.3.4 at 2011-03-07 09:39:22 -0800
  Processing by WidgetsController#noaudio as HTML
  Parameters: blah blah blah
Redirected to http://mydomain.com/mainhandler
Completed 302 Found in 1ms
```

Am I using redirect_to incorrectly? or does it not work for a POST? (Although I would presumably still see at least a GET)

Comment: AFAICS there should be a redirect, really. What happens in the browser? Not important for an answer, just by the way, why is this a POST? There's no data, this could also just be a GET?

Comment: yes the remote system always POSTS data to my app...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirects do not work for POSTs indeed.

You may want to take a look at that for some more info :

[redirect_to using POST in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* must have this middleman and want to POST on the data to a new URL, you could use [Ruby's Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) class and pass on the data.

I think you should think twice though and ask yourself if this is really what you want to do.