# Redirect user to external url with post method and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, http-post, httparty

How do i redirect user to external url via post method? I know `redirect_to` works only for `get` requests. How do i achieve this?

Comment: I am curious. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @KaiMattern me too. Thats what i've been ordered to do :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect\_to using POST in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails)

Comment: No. 6 years long distance. A lot changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot redirect a user to a `POST` method. You can present a user with a link that the Rails JS will turn into a form/POST:

```
= link_to "Do it!", "http://other.site/path", method: :post
```

...or a form that triggers a `POST` to another site (note that I've included an extra param in this) eg.

```
= form_tag "http://other.site/path", method: :post do
  = hidden_field_tag :foo, "Bar"
  = submit_tag "Do it!"
```

...or you can make the request yourself from the server side on your user's behalf (here I'm using the [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem), note that I'm including the same `foo=Bar` parameters:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  include HTTParty

  def some_action
    self.class.post "http://other.site/path", query: { foo: "Bar" }
  end
end
```

A few options for you.

Comment: Ended up on Httparty solution too