# How do I redirect with POST params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm integrating a credit card payment system to my Rails app. In their documentation it says that I have to redirect the user to the payment form with POST parameters.

**Here is what it says in the documentation:**

When creating an post please use UTF8 encoding.

When a merchant redirects a buyer to the Corvus Form Service he must redirect to the following url:

- For testing purposes: 
  https://testcps.corvus.hr/redirect/

With the following POST parameters:

```
target=_top&mode=form&store_id=101&order_number=1233&language=hr&currency=H
RK&amount=123.54&cart=2xLCDTV&hash=6cb317d8b6ade738cb9dc02cae220b3bd2b4bc82
&require_complete=false
```

The redirect url must look like:

https://testcps.corvus.hr/redirect/

The redirect url must **not** look like:

```
https://testcps.corvus.hr/redirect/?target=_top&mode=form&store_id=101&orde
r_number=1233&language=hr&currency=HRK&amount=123.54&cart=2xLCDTV&hash=c9a5
3c3525e557da
```

Do not use the GET method to redirect a user to CorvusPay payment form.

The redirect of a user does not require the use of an SSL certificate.

Comment: Means you have to add your params to the body of the request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect user to external url with post method and params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103568/redirect-user-to-external-url-with-post-method-and-params)

Comment: it works perfectly fine