# sending params using post in rails to an external application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to ruby on rails. In my rails app, when the user logs in, I need to redirect him along with some info related to the user to an external application( a https url which ends in .action) using POST. Since redirection is a GET request, can somebody give me some pointers?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/985599/4739257 - duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `POST` requests to an external application easily using the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)