# Rails Form: post to external form and redirect to external response page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, cross-domain

Is there a way for the customer to fill in the credential in my Rails App and the app posts to an external form?

If the credentials are correct, the customer will be redirected to the external response page.

As if my Rails App is behaving as the external website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to external page with `GET` method but I can't do this via `POST`.

```
if user_signed_in?
  redirect_to http://external.page/ # this will use GET METHOD
end
```

[redirect_to using POST in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails)

This answer your question?